# BIRT Report viewer taking long time to load from spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, birt

I am using BIRT reports viewer in my spring mvc web application and loading it in my jsp's using the birt tags. I am finding that the birt report viewer is taking a very long time to load.

Just as an example I took one of my particular reports, ran it in eclipse and then ran the same report in my webapp on my server through my web application and there was a significant amount of extra time loading the report through my web application on the server.

Can anyone tell me some of the tricks I can try to imporve the report viewer load time. Just in case it helps I have attached the ReportEngine_2014_09_30_13_27_50.log output from running my report on the server. http://pastebin.com/htxEiQ4y . It's taking about 10 seconds too long.

Maybe there are some caching suggestions?

thanks

Comment: What about your current JVM settings?  In particular try to set your "MaxPermSize" property to 512m, and your heap memory to something like -Xmx2048M

Comment: thanks...My settings in the websphere console are Initial Heap Size 1224 and Maximum Heap Size 1224. I'm not sure if your settings directly correspond to these fileds but I will do some research into it. Is it normally recommended this be done for the BIRT reports viewer to run properly?

Comment: Yes you should increase this heap size, especially with websphere because it consumes a significant bunch of memory. Additionnally, as mentionned you also probably need to increase the size of the permanent memory. As far as i know there are no set rules for these settings with BIRT: it highly depends on the kind of reports, if there are many charts or not, if reports execution can be concurrent etc. Furthermore, don't forget the execution time of BIRT reports is directly proportional to the processor speed, in case you make your tests on different machines.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. As of today I have set -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m and also -XX:MaxPermSize=512M. I am not very familiar with these settings but hop it will help. Just from initial observations it doesn't seem to imporve things but I'll observe performance over the next few days.